# Issue with XIB in new Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xib, nib

I have a problem with the new Xcode (today I upgraded). When I push on my file `view.xib`, I see the `XML` code, and not the graphics interface. Why? How can I see the "interface builder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XIB File opens like an XML in XCode but opens correctly with Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151983/xib-file-opens-like-an-xml-in-xcode-but-opens-correctly-with-interface-builder)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that this is the second time someone has had this problem. You can open the `File Inspector` on the Utilities bar on the right ( Opt+Cmd+1 ). Change the `File Type` under `Identity and Type` to the topmost choice. It should be `Default - com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB`.

Comment: Thanks! And just to make things clear for others, the File Inspector is part of Xcode, not a separate application.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the .xib file and select "Open As". Then select "Xcode.IDEKit.TouchCodeIntegration.EditorDocument.CocoaTouch-title"